# Question about a proof of PA$_2$'s categoricity

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, predicate-logic, peano-axioms, higher-order-logic

Here is a proof of the categoricity of second-order Peano arithmetic. I have trouble understanding a part of it. Let $\mathfrak N=(V',\mathbb N,\text P(\mathbb N),\text P(\mathbb N^2),\text P(\mathbb N^3),...)$ be the standard model and $\mathfrak M=(V,D,\text P(D),\text P(D^2),\text P(D^3),...)$ be a full model for PA$_2$ where $D,\text P(D^n)$s are carriers for individuals and relations and $V$ assigns constant symbols to elements of their carriers. The proof shows there is a $\tilde0\in D$ and a successor $\sigma(a)$ for each $a\in D$. It then constructs a yet-to-be-proved isomorphism $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow D,f(0)=\tilde 0,f(n+1)=\sigma(f(n))$ and shows it's injective. To prove it is surjective, it claims that

> On the other hand $\tilde0=f(0)\in f(\mathbb N)\subseteq D$ then $\sigma(a)=f(n+1)\in f(\mathbb N)\subseteq D$. Thus $\mathfrak M\vDash\forall x[\mbox Z_0(x)\rightarrow\textbf M(x)]$ and $\mathfrak M\vDash\forall x\forall y[\textbf M(x)\rightarrow[\mbox S(x,y)\rightarrow\mathbf M(y)]]$ where $\textbf M=f(\mathbb N)$

and then uses axiom of induction to proceed. S($y,x$) is intended to mean $x=y+1$ and Z$_0(x)$:=$\forall y$~S($y,x$).

What I don't understand is the use of $\textbf M$. $\textbf M$ is not a symbol in the object language so it must be a meta-symbol to be substituted by something in the object language. But $\textbf M=f(\mathbb N)$? Does it mean M is to be replaced by $f(\mathbb N)$ like macros in C or they have same denotation? I doubt the first case because $f(\mathbb N)$ is also in the metalanguage denoting a semantical thing.

The proof is from [*Mathematical Logic: A First Course* by Joel W. Robbin](http://www.filedropper.com/mathematicallogicafirstcourse), page 162. Thanks.
[image: Categoricity of PA2]

Comment: I'm not able to check the details about Robbin's treatment of $\mathsf {PA_2}$, but you have to take into account that it uses secon-order logic, with comprehension, and thus it must work set theory-like.

Comment: The def of $f$ is by recursion; thus (in SOL as well as set theory) we can prove that there is a unique function $f$ satisfying the recursive def. By comprehnesion, we may add to the language the symbol denoting that unique function...

Comment: See **Ex.8**, page 169. Maybe relevant ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think this explanation should be good. The fact that the axiom of induction is true in $\mathfrak M$ means meta-induction is valid in $\mathfrak M$, that is, $\mathfrak M$ is the smallest inductive set generated by $\sigma$ and $\tilde0$ freely(read in metalanguage) so $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow D$ is epi.

Comment: $\mathfrak M$ being a full model is relevant. The induction axiom says $\forall A$ if $x=\tilde0\rightarrow x\in A$ and $x\in A\rightarrow Sx\in A$ then $A$ is the universe. $\mathfrak M$ being full means $A$ varys through the whole $2^D$ which contains $f(\mathbb N)$